# Using NSNotification in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to use NSNotification in my `Storyboard`.

This code work when I don't use storyboard.

this is in ViewController1:

```
- (IBAction) buttonClickedListener2:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"TestNotification"
     object:self];
}
```

And this is in ViewController2:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                     name:@"TestNotification"
                                                   object:nil];

        NSLog(@"initWithNib");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"TestNotification"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
}
```

Is it anything wrong with the codes? As I said I want to make it work in my Storyboard.

I appreciate if you give me some toturials about how to use NSNotification in `STORYBOARD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboards don't use `initWithNibName`, so the part of your code where you add your observer doesn't get run. You should be able to see this by setting a breakpoint. A fix would be to replace

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self){
        //statements
    }
    return self;
}
```

with

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self){
        //statements
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are totally right about initWithNibName. but when I use `initWithCoder´, it shows a warning : `Control reaches end of non-void function`. And it did not work. Even I can not navigate to second viewController using Push.

Comment: @Ali may be you missed the return val of initWithCoder methods write as  `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`

Comment: Yes, but did not work. `initWithCoder` is called when we navigate to second ViewController.

Comment: Apologies, I edited my answer to add the missing (id) in front of initWithCoder.

Comment: Do you still see the warning "Control reaches end of non-void function"? It shouldn't happen. If it does can you please copy/paste your initWithCoder method?

Comment: When I navigate to second view and then again navigate to first one. Now: it works, but not at first. Because the initWithCoder will not called until I navigate. any idea please?

Comment: No the warning is disappeared.

Comment: @Ali this notification wont be recieved until the view controller is created and navigated to. The fact it still recieves the notification after it has been dismissed means you may have a memory leak. `NSNotification`s might not be the right tool for what you want to do

Answer (score 3):

You should be adding observer NOT in `initWithNibName` but in `awakeFromNib`. `initWithNibName` is not called for storyboards.

For instance:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Comment: When I navigate to second view and then again navigate to first one: it works. but not at first. Because the `initWithCoder`or `awakeFromNib`  will not called until I navigate. any idea please?

Comment: You shouldn't be receiving notifications if the `viewController` object isn't there. If you have some actions to perform on such notification then register for it in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and point some data model method, that way it will prepare some data so later you can use it in your `viewController` for instance in `viewWillAppear` to reload some table.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks Ok.

Here The problem could be,You are  posting `Notification` From the `ViewController1` and adding that `Notification` to The `ViewController2`.

Check Whether `Notification` has added properly before posting ,it may be possible `notification` has not added when you were trying to post that `notification`.

one more thing just debug properly check whether `initWithNibName` called or not.
I think storyboard don't use `initWithNibName` so you should use `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` instead of initWithNibName.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Do you have any example that can show me how to use NSNotification in Storyboard in a right way?

Comment: @Ali one thing just debug properly check whether `initWithNibName` called  or not.use this  `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` instead of  `initWithNibName` .